# ACF repeater subfield for meta query

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is my meta query.. (var_dump mode)

```
array(2) { 
    ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" 
    [0]=> array(2) { 
        ["relation"]=> string(2) "OR" 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
            ["key"]=> string(17) "status_$_bedrooms" 
            ["value"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["compare"]=> string(1) "=" 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I set more nested meta queries in case that other fields has any value..
This is a case of a repeater subfield I added the following filter but with no luck.. I don't know if has to do with my query's structure

```
function my_posts_where( $where ) {
    $where = str_replace("meta_key = 'status_$", "meta_key LIKE 'status_%", $where);
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where');
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem..
the value is string.. I had to convert it to integer with intval() to compare number with number